# What is a minimal strongly connected component?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, terminology, connectedness, directed-graphs

I have a problem that states:

> Prove true or false: If G= (V, E) is a directed graph, then the first vertex that becomes black when  applying  the  DFS  algorithm  on G,  belongs  to  a  minimal strongly connected component.

I looked it up on Google (obviously), but could not find any information on a "minimal strongly connected component". I am not sure what the question is asking. Any help?

Thank you

Comment: I am not a graph theorist, but *minimal* seems weird, *maximal strongly connected component* would make more sense to me.

Comment: @C.Falcon Would it be true if it were maximal? I cannot think of a situation where it would be false. The minimal part is tripping me up, I do not know what that could even mean

Comment: As I said, not a graph theorist, so I don't even know what DFS algorithm is and I have no clue whether or not this statement is true. Either way, a minimal strongly connected component of $G$ would be a set $S$ of vertices of $G$ such that there exists a path of transitions of $G$ between any two elements of $S$ and if $S'\subset S$ is another such set of vertices, then $S=S'$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you do know? Without the specifics of how DFS is described in the source you're using, it's hard to say what it means for a vertex to "become black".

Comment: It seems to me that a "minimal strongly connected component" of a graph $G$ is a strongly-connected subgraph of $G$, say $C$, with the property that no proper subgraph of $C$ is strongly connected. Note that such components need not cover all of $G$. For example consider the graph with edges $AB, BC,  CB$.  Then the subgraph induced by $\{B,C\}$ is a minimal strongly connected component, and $A$ is not in any strongly connected component at all. Now suppose you start DFS at $A$. The claim is that one of $B$ or $C$, not $A$, will be the first vertex colored black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it can help you
Given a graph $G = (V,E)$, a set of vertices $S ⊆ V$ is said to be *strongly connected* if for any $v_1, v_2 ∈ S$, the graph contains a path through $S$ from  $v_1$ to $v_2$.
A *loop* of a graph is a non-empty, strongly connected set of vertices.

A *strongly connected component* of G = (V, E) is a maximal subgraph $G′ =
(V ′, E′)$ of $G$ such that $V ′$ is strongly connected.

- By $SCC_G$ we denote the set
  $\{V ′ | G′ = (V ′, E′)$ is a strongly connected component of G$\}$.

We define the $SCC$-partition of $G$, denoted $SCC^+_G$, as the 
set $SCC_G ∪ \{\{v\}|v\in G $ and $v$ does not occur in a loop of G$\} $.
Observe that $SCC^+_G$ indeed forms a partition of $V$ .

We define a relation $≼_G$ on the $SCC$-partition of $G$:  for $S_1,S_2 ∈ SCC^+_G$, $S_1 ≼_G S_2$ if for some $v_1 ∈S_1,v_2 ∈S_2$,there is a path in $G$ from $v_2$ to $v_1$, or if $S_1 =S_2 =\{v\}$,where $v$ does not occur in a loop of G.
Note that $≼_G$ is now also defined on the strongly connected components of G, since $SCC_G ⊆ SCC^+_G$.

> **minimal strongly connected component of $G$:** this is a component $G′ =
>  (V′,E′)$ such that there is no $V′′ ∈ SCC_G$ with $V′′ \ne V′$ and
>   $V′′ ≼_G V′$. Note that in general there may be several such minimal
>   components.

---

[MODEL GENERATION FOR ID-LOGIC [Prof. Dr. M. DENECKER]](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/1979/2094/2/thesis_printable.pdf) Page [$50$], $4.2.3$ Some graph concepts